# How manage data upload sent PutExtra

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I am sending the data between activities, through PutExtra. It's working perfectly.

The problem is when you click the back button, give an error and for the activity.
I've already tried to implement the StarActivityForResult option, and I can not get it to work.

Images below. Code "12345" is used as an example, and is sent to the three screens as PutExtra

[image] [image][image]

Code: 
Activity1:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Button btnIrAct2;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        btnIrAct2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnIrAct2);
        btnIrAct2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                Intent intent2 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Activity2.class);
                intent2.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                intent2.putExtra("id_empresa", "12345");
                startActivity(intent2);

            }
        });


    }
}
```

Activity 2:

```
public class Activity2 extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Button btnIrAct3;
    private String mId_Empresa = null;
    static final int SERVICO_DETALHES_REQUEST = 1;
    private TextView tvResultado;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_2);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);



        /*  Recebe id de outra tela*/
        mId_Empresa = getIntent().getExtras().getString("id_empresa");

        tvResultado = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvAct2);
        tvResultado.setText(mId_Empresa);

        btnIrAct3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnIrAct3);
        btnIrAct3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                Intent intent3 = new Intent(Activity2.this, Activity3.class);
                intent3.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                intent3.putExtra("id_empresa", "12345");
                startActivityForResult(intent3, SERVICO_DETALHES_REQUEST );

            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
    {
        if (requestCode == SERVICO_DETALHES_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            String resultBack = data.getStringExtra("id_empresa");
        }
    }

}
```

Activity 3:

```
public class Activity3 extends AppCompatActivity {

    private String idEmpresa = null;
    private TextView resultado;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_3);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        /*  Recebe id de outra tela*/
        idEmpresa = getIntent().getExtras().getString("id_empresa");

        resultado = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvAct3);
        resultado.setText(idEmpresa);


    }

    @Override
    public void finish()
    {
        Intent data = new Intent();
        data.putExtra("id_empresa", "12345");
        setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, data);
        super.finish();
    }

}
```

I need to resolve the conflict. Because on my return I need to send a data like PutExtra, at the same time that this Activity already has a piece of code that already receives a PutExtra.

Comment: which error `give an error and for the activity`  an unclear problem statement will likely not to get any help to you so explain the exact issue

Comment: are you unable to retrieve data in activity 2 inside `onActivityResult`?

Comment: Yes. When I close Activity 3 I would like to display Activity 2 but since it expects a GetExtra at the beginning of the error and says that the object is null. @Pavneet_Singh

Comment: it's still not clear to me what exactly you want , but seems like a situation for `sharedpreference` store your small data and fetch it from any activity

Comment: What is the exact error and what line causes it?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the issue correctly, you should to use fragments instead of activities and save all the data in main activity but if you want to continue with this way try onBackPressed() method to choose what to do when the user pressed back button.

Comment: Sim, tentei isso. Diz que objeto é nulo. Because Activity 2 expects this data: mId_Empresa = getIntent().getExtras().getString("id_empresa"); @Royi

Comment: This data first came from Activity 1 to Activity 2, so it will always be the first function to perform

Answer (score 0):

Insert this code in Activity 2

```
             if(getIntent().getExtras().getString("id_empresa") != null)
             {
             mId_Empresa = getIntent().getExtras().getString("id_empresa");
             }
```

Checking the data before setting it to the textview is must. If the string you are putting to textview is null, it will generate an error which will lead to crash.
Hope it helps!